# PHP error with curl bracket and dollar sign

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
$test = "XXXXX";
$message = "Look at this {$test I am} running";
echo $message;
```

I'm expecting to get this:

```
Look at this {XXXXX I am} running
```

But instead I'm getting an error.  I've narrowed the error down to `{$`.

I'd normally just type the problematic part into Google, but searching for `"{$"`. doesn't work.

Why am I getting this error and what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In double-quoted strings, `{$variable}` is one of the ways to substitute a variable into the string. So it's trying to substitute a variable named `test I am`, which is not a valid variable name.

Since you want the `{` to be treated literally, not as introducing a variable substitution, you need to wrap `$test` in `{}`.

```
$test = "XXXXX";
$message = "Look at this {{$test} I am} running";
echo $message;
```